Text editor crashes because of Enchant spelling dictionary (?) in Ubuntu 24.10
I get this error when running xdg-open INSTALL:
ERROR:../lib/enchant/spelling-enchant-dictionary.c:87:spelling_enchant_dictionary_contains_word: assertion failed: (word_len > 0) Bail out! 
ERROR:../lib/enchant/spelling-enchant-dictionary.c:87:spelling_enchant_dictionary_contains_word: assertion failed: (word_len > 0)

I suppose this is also what happens when it crashes after being opened 'normally' from the dock.
I have some text files that have Japanese characters and some random characters that I found when looking through the character map that I just thought looked cool. I suspect these are crashing the editor (because it opens all of them at once), but of course I don't really know.
I deleted the files with funky characters and this did not help.
